# querybuilder join query in Doctrine2 for Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Could somebody convert this query for me in querybuilder?

```
SELECT m.id,n.unitid 
  FROM mappaths m JOIN unitids n on (m.id=n.id) where n.databaseid=1
```

I am using this query but it gives me all the values of `mm.unitid`, while my requirement is to get only one value that is defined by `test=1` variable

```
    $query=$qb->select('mm.unitid')
      ->from('ApiMapBundle:Mappaths','m')
      ->from('ApiMapBundle:Unitids','mm')
     // ->leftJoin('m','u')
       ->leftJoin('m.refUnitids1','u','WITH','m.id = u')
     //  ->leftJoin('m.refUnitids2','v')   
      ->where('m.id=:test')
      ->setParameter('test',1)
      ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Why are you using leftJoin in queryBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
$query = $qb->select('mm.unitid')
      ->from('ApiMapBundle:Mappaths','m')
      ->innerJoin('m.refUnitids1','mm','WITH','m.id = mm.FIELD') //you need to specify on which field of mm join should be done
      ->where('m.id=:test')
      ->setParameter('test',1)
      ->getQuery()
      ->getResult();
```

You need to specify field of `Unitids` which should be used to join to `Mappaths`. The best way would be to define this relation in `Entity` definition, then you can use just `->innerJoin('m.refUnitids1','mm')` without additional join parameters.

Also, in this case, it is better to use `innerJoin` instead of `leftJoin`

Comment: Tomasz thanks for your response. one more question if we would have two foreign keys then how would be the query in this case for example the query like this in sql=                   select *
  FROM mappaths m JOIN unitids n on( m.ref_unitids2 = n.id or m.ref_unitids1 = n.id) where m.id=2

Comment: i already define these forign-- primary relationship in meta files. basically this mappaths table (class) contain two (many to one) relationships to unitds table. or class..